# Parallax effect making background bigger than the container where it's located

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I have a code which is creating white space on the right side of the page because the background is bigger than the container and I don't know how to fix that if I want to keep my background parallaxed.

Are there any ideas how to fix that?

```js
var lFollowX = 0,
  lFollowY = 0,
  x = 0,
  y = 0,
  friction = 1 / 60;

function moveBackground() {
  x += (lFollowX - x) * friction;
  y += (lFollowY - y) * friction;

  translate = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px) scale(1.1)';

  $('#home-background').css({
    '-webit-transform': translate,
    '-moz-transform': translate,
    'transform': translate
  });

  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveBackground);
}

$(window).on('mousemove click', function(e) {

  var lMouseX = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).width() / 2 - e.clientX));
  var lMouseY = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).height() / 2 - e.clientY));
  lFollowX = (20 * lMouseX) / 100; // 100 : 12 = lMouxeX : lFollow
  lFollowY = (10 * lMouseY) / 100;

});

moveBackground();
```

```css
#home-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("https://www.tokkoro.com/picsup/5746854-geometry-wallpapers.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #251524;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home">
  <div id="home-background"></div>
  <div id="greeting">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: It may help others to answer your question if you also include your HTML/CSS code.

Comment: oh, okay. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the background `div` is expanding beyond the limits of the container is because, by using `transform: translate(...)`, you are moving the background outside the container.

If, instead of moving the background beyond the container, you want to move the background and clip its edges to match the container, you will likely need to use some form of `overflow: hidden`, which prevents the container from showing anything outside its bounds.

In the case of the code you posted, you can simply add `overflow: hidden` to the `body` element:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

However, you may not necessarily want to add `overflow: hidden` to the body if you need to allow overflow somewhere else on the page. In that case, you can wrap your `#home` and `#menu` sections in a `div` that has `overflow: hidden` applied to it. Note that you also need to add `position: relative` to this `div` for it to work.

For example, here is an updated version of your HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <section id="home">
    <div id="home-background"></div>
    <div id="greeting">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is a code snippet demonstrating this solution:

```js
var lFollowX = 0,
  lFollowY = 0,
  x = 0,
  y = 0,
  friction = 1 / 60;

function moveBackground() {
  x += (lFollowX - x) * friction;
  y += (lFollowY - y) * friction;

  translate = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px) scale(1.1)';

  $('#home-background').css({
    '-webit-transform': translate,
    '-moz-transform': translate,
    'transform': translate
  });

  window.requestAnimationFrame(moveBackground);
}

$(window).on('mousemove click', function(e) {

  var lMouseX = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).width() / 2 - e.clientX));
  var lMouseY = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).height() / 2 - e.clientY));
  lFollowX = (20 * lMouseX) / 100; // 100 : 12 = lMouxeX : lFollow
  lFollowY = (10 * lMouseY) / 100;

});

moveBackground();
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

#home-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("https://www.tokkoro.com/picsup/5746854-geometry-wallpapers.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #251524;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section id="home">
    <div id="home-background"></div>
    <div id="greeting">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works!
It seems that it works even if I don't type "position: relative" but in this case, there's a problem only on the mobile version. I feel like I gotta refresh my knowledge about position attribute.

Comment: @nosferatume Hmm, interesting. Perhaps it's a browser issue then, because I have to add `position: relative` to it in order to get it to work on my computer in both Chrome and Firefox. Also, if the solution worked, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.